# Error when running OpenGL project under Ubuntu 10.10

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, ubuntu-10.10

I had OpenGL project for finding a convex hull written in Windows.

Now i'm using Ubuntu 10.10 and i tried to port the code (It's C++ code) and run it.

I saw that, it should be compiled this way :

```
g++ convex.cpp -lm -lglut -lGLU -o convex_hull_project
```

It compiles the file, but when i run the file `./convex_hull_project` it starts the program, shows the title but there is nothing - it only docks for the bottom task line and when i click it - nothing shows. **There is no window with the program.**
Any idea ?
Here's the code that uses OpenGL stuff :

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_DEPTH); // color, buffer
    glutInitWindowPosition(100,100);
    glutInitWindowSize(window_size_width,window_size_height);
    glutCreateWindow("Convex hull");
    glutDisplayFunc(renderScene);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}


void renderScene(void) {

    // clear framebuffer
    glClearColor(0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set-up matrix
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,window_size_width,window_size_height,0,-1,1);

    glViewport(0,0,window_size_width,window_size_height);
        //drawing ... 
    }
```

And includes are :

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<GL/glu.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<math.h>
```

Comment: Since you get the executable, your program is compiled and linked, it just doesn't work ax expected - the title is misleading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `glutCreateWindow` **before** you set windows's properties. Your code, fixed (I've replaced width and height constants with 300 just to get it to compile and commented out mouse handler registration):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>

void renderScene(void) {

    // clear framebuffer
    glClearColor (0.f,0.f,0.f,0.f);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    // set-up matrix
    glMatrixMode (GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity ();
    glOrtho (0, 300, 300, 0,-1,1);

    glViewport (0,0,300, 300);
    //drawing ... 
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit (&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_DEPTH); // color, buffer
    glutCreateWindow ("Convex hull");
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize (300, 300);
    glutDisplayFunc (renderScene);
    //glutMouseFunc (mouse);
    glutMainLoop ();
}
```

Comment: glutCreateWindow ("Hello, GLUT Window!");
    glutInitWindowPosition (100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize (300, 300);
    glutCreateWindow ("Convex hull");
I'm creating the window :)

Comment: Right, but you have to create it before you set its properties... So I haven't even noticed it after those init calls :-)

Comment: Okay, it creates the window but does not show it.
I click on the place where the window should be and get the output in the  console. Very weird

Comment: Okay, everything's fine. When i run it from the folder, it display properly.
Thank you for your help, you pointed me the direction to look for ;)

Comment: @Vlad Lazarenko i have the same error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914315/problem-with-glut even with opening it from the folder